# How I display a string obtained from a matrix?

Tags: c, string, matrix

It is considered a rectangular matrix, with m rows and n columns. Determine and display the minimum element of the matrix and its position, given by the row number and column number. Form a string containing all the elements of the matrix that are divisible by the minimum element. Display the obtained string. (If the minimum item is zero, the program stops after determining and displaying it).

This is the program so far:

```
int main()
{
  int m, n, c, d, mat[100][100], minim;
  printf("Introdu numarul de linii si coloane al matricei\n");
  scanf("%d%d",&m,&n);
  printf("Introdu elementele matricei\n");
  for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for(d = 0; d < n; d++)
      scanf("%d", &mat[c][d]);
      printf("\nMatricea este:\n");
for(c = 0; c < m ; c++)
{
    for(d = 0; d < n; d++)
    {
        printf("%d",mat[c][d]);
        printf("\t");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
  minim = mat[0][0];
  for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
      if (mat[c][d] < minim)
        minim = mat[c][d];
  printf("Elemenul minim al matricei este %d\n", minim);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Too many non-specific question....

Comment: To check whether an element of the matrix is divisible by `minim`, use `if (mat[c][d] % minim == 0)`

Comment: I don't know how to do the last part: Form a string containing all the elements of the matrix that are divisible by the minimum element. Display the obtained string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether an element of the matrix is divisible by `minim`, use the condition:

```
if ((mat[c][d] % minim) == 0)
```

You can use `sprintf` to convert `int` to string, then using `strcat` to concatenate string with another string.

The code for storing the values in string (add this code in your main function):

```
     char * str = malloc(10);
     if(!str) {
       return -1;
     }

      int len = 0;
      for (c = 0; c < m; c++)
        for (d = 0; d < n; d++)
          if ((mat[c][d] % minim) == 0) {
            char temp[10];
            len += strlen(str) + 10;
            sprintf(temp, "%d ", mat[c][d]);
            str = realloc(str, len);
            if(!str) {
               return -1;
            }
            strcat(str, temp);
          }

       printf("string: %s\n", str);
       free(str);
```

The output of test:

```
Introdu numarul de linii si coloane al matricei
3 2
Introdu elementele matricei
100 2 500 700 800 900
100 2   
500 700 
800 900 
Elemenul minim al matricei este 2
str : 100 2 500 700 800 900
```